# Property in JS class is not changing the value, always is undefined

Tags: javascript

This is a part of code for make an Snake Game in JS, the problem is that I want to set oldDirection the actual direction to make an animation with the sprites in the U-turns but `this.direction` is having new value but `oldDirection` is always `undefined`.

```
class SnakeBody {
  constructor(x, y, ctx) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.oldX
    this.oldY
    this.ctx = ctx
    this.direction
    this.oldDirection
    this.sprite = new Image()
  }
  // Draws Players Body taking direction from head to set the direction of sprite
  draw(headDirection) {
    this.direction = headDirection
    this.sprite.onload = () => {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y, 20, 20)
    }
  }

  // Update Player Body to new X and Y, and this must receive direction to change sprite
  update(newX, newY, newDirection) {
    // Problem here OldDirection doesn't get the address value
    this.oldDirection = this.direction
    this.direction = newDirection

    this.ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20)

    this.oldX = this.x
    this.oldY = this.y
    this.x = newX;
    this.y = newY;

    this.sprite.onload = () => {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y, 20, 20)
    }
  }

  setDirection(nDirection) {
    this.oldDirection = this.direction
    this.direction = nDirection
  }

  getDirection() {
    return this.direction
  }

  // Sets the sprite for the snake body
  setSnakeSpriteDirection(newDirection) {
    switch (true) {
      case this.direction == 'DOWN' && newDirection == 'LEFT':
        this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeBody_rotateDownLeft.png'
        break
      case this.direction == 'UP' || this.direction == 'UP' &&
      newDirection == 'DOWN' || this.direction == 'DOWN':
        this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeBody_down.png'
        break;
      case this.direction == 'RIGHT' || this.direction == 'RIGHT' &&
      newDirection == 'LEFT' || this.direction == 'LEFT':
        this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeBody_left.png'
        break;
      default:
        this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeBody_left.png'
        break;
    }

    this.draw()
  }
}
```

EDIT:

SnakeBody:

```js
class SnakeBody {
    constructor(x, y, ctx) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.oldX
        this.oldY
        this.ctx = ctx
        this.direction
        this.oldDirection
        this.sprite = new Image()
    }

    draw(headDirection) {
        this.direction = headDirection
        this.sprite.onload = () => {
            this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y, 20, 20)
        }
    }

    update(newX, newY, newDirection) {
        this.oldDirection = this.direction
        this.direction = newDirection
        this.ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20)

        console.log('This.Direction:', this.direction, 'This.oldDirection:', this.oldDirection);

        this.oldX = this.x
        this.oldY = this.y
        this.x = newX;
        this.y = newY;
        
        this.sprite.onload = () => {
            this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y, 20, 20)
        }
    }

    setDirection(nDirection) {
        this.oldDirection = this.direction
        this.direction = nDirection
    }

    getDirection() {
        return this.direction
    }

    setSnakeSpriteDirection(newDirection) {
        switch(true) {
            case this.direction == 'DOWN' && newDirection == 'LEFT':
                this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeBody_rotateDownLeft.png'
                break
            case this.direction == 'UP' || this.direction == 'UP' 
            && newDirection == 'DOWN' || this.direction == 'DOWN':
                this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeBody_down.png'
                break;
            case this.direction == 'RIGHT' || this.direction == 'RIGHT' 
            && newDirection == 'LEFT' || this.direction == 'LEFT':
                this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeBody_left.png'
                break;
            default:
                this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeBody_left.png'
                break;
        }

        this.draw()
    }
}
```

Player Class:

```js
class Player {
    constructor(x, y, name, ctx) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.oldX;
        this.oldY;
        this.name = name;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.direction
        this.oldDirection
        this.body = []
        this.sprite = new Image()
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    draw() {
        switch (this.getDirection()) {
            case 'UP':
                this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeHead.png'
                break;
            case 'DOWN':
                this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeHead_down.png'
                break;
            case 'RIGHT':
                this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeHead_right.png'
                break;
            case 'LEFT':
                this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeHead_left.png'
                break;
            default: 
                this.sprite.src = 'src/assets/img/snakeHead.png'
                break;
        }

        this.sprite.onload = () => {
            this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprite, this.x, this.y, 20, 20)
        }
    }

    update(newX, newY) {
        this.ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20)

        this.x = newX;
        this.y = newY;
    }

    updateBody() {
        if (this.body.length > 0) {
            this.body.forEach((bodyPart, index) => {
                
                if( index == 0 ) {
                    bodyPart.update(this.x, this.y, this.oldDirection)
                    bodyPart.setSnakeSpriteDirection(this.direction)
                } else {
                    bodyPart.update(
                        this.body[index - 1].oldX, 
                        this.body[index - 1].oldY, 
                        this.body[index - 1].oldDirection
                    )
                    bodyPart.setSnakeSpriteDirection(this.body[index - 1].getDirection())   
                }
            })
        }
    }

    
    movement() {
        this.updateBody()
        this.oldY = this.y
        this.oldX = this.x

        switch (this.direction) {
            case 'DOWN':
                this.y != 380
                    ? this.update(this.x, this.y + 20)
                    : this.update(this.x, 0)
                break;
            case 'UP':
                this.y == 0
                    ? this.update(this.x, 380)
                    : this.update(this.x, this.y - 20)
                break;
            case 'LEFT':
                this.x == 0
                    ? this.update(380, this.y)
                    : this.update(this.x - 20, this.y)
                break;
            case 'RIGHT':
                this.x != 380
                    ? this.update(this.x + 20, this.y)
                    : this.update(0, this.y)
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        this.oldDirection = this.direction
    }

    setDirection(direction) {
        this.oldDirection = this.direction
        this.direction = direction
    }

    getDirection() {
        return this.direction
    }

    checkCollision(block) {
        if (
            this.x < block.x + 20 &&
            this.x + 20 > block.x &&
            this.y < block.y + 20 &&
            this.y + 20 > block.y
            ) {
                let newBody = new SnakeBody(this.x, this.y, this.ctx)
                newBody.setDirection()
                this.body.push(newBody)
            }
    }
    
}
```

Game: (Where I set the Player direction):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    const canvasGame = document.querySelector('canvas')
    const ctx = canvasGame.getContext('2d')

    const 
    cHeight = canvasGame.height = 400,
    cWidth = canvasGame.width = 400;

    let cells = 20;

    const drawGrid = () => {
        ctx.lineWidth = 1.1
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#232332'
        ctx.shadowBlur = 0

        for (let i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
            let f = (cHeight / cells) * i

            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(f, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(f, cHeight)
            ctx.stroke()

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0, f)
            ctx.lineTo(cHeight, f)
            ctx.stroke()

            ctx.closePath()
            
        }
    }

    const drawPlayer = () => {        
        let playerX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 - 0 + 1) * 20
        let foodX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 - 0 + 1) * 20
        let foodY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 - 0 + 1) * 20
        let playerY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 - 0 + 1) * 20

        let food = new Food(foodX, foodY, 'red', ctx)
        let player = new Player(playerX, playerY, 'Moises', ctx)
        
        player.draw()
        food.draw()

        document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    player.setDirection('LEFT')
                    break;
                case 39:
                    player.setDirection('RIGHT')
                    break
                case 38:
                    player.setDirection('UP')
                    break
                case 40:
                    player.setDirection('DOWN')
                    break;
            }
        })

        setInterval(() => {
            player.movement()
            player.checkCollision(food)
            food.collision(player)
            player.draw()
            food.draw()
            drawGrid()
        }, 450)
    }

    drawGrid()
    drawPlayer()
})
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Food Class:

```js
class Food {
    constructor(x, y, color, ctx) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.color = color
        this.ctx = ctx
    }

    draw() {
        let img = new Image()

        img.src = 'src/assets/img/apple.png'
        img.onload = () => {
            this.ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
            // this.ctx.fillStyle = this.color
            // this.ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20)
        }

    }

    update(newX, newY) {
        this.ctx.clearRect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20)

        this.x = newX;
        this.y = newY;

        // this.ctx.fillRect(newX, newY, 20, 20)
    }

    collision(player) {
        let newX = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 - 0 + 1)) * 20;
        let newY = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 - 0 + 1)) * 20;

        if (
            player.x < this.x + 20 &&
            player.x + 20 > this.x &&
            player.y < this.y + 20 &&
            player.y + 20 > this.y
            ) {
                this.update(newX, newY)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us where you set and test `this.oldDirection` of the instantiated object as well?

Comment: How are you calling setDirection?

Comment: i called `this.setDirection(newDirection)` because I used inside `this.update`

Comment: I added `<canvas></canvas>` to the last snippet but still errors on  `player.checkCollision(food)
            food.collision(player)` `food` is not defined

Comment: FWIW at some point not having semi-colons on lines will bite you with a difficult to find but.

Comment: I'm going to edit it

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me.

```js
class SnakeBody {
  constructor() {
    this.direction
    this.oldDirection
  }
  
  test( newDirection ) {
    this.oldDirection = this.direction;
    this.direction = newDirection;
  }
}

const snake = new SnakeBody();
snake.test( 1 );
snake.test( 2 );
console.log( snake.oldDirection );
```

EDIT:

i'm guessing your problem is here, in your player class:

```
 index == 0
                    ? (
                        bodyPart.update(this.x, this.y, this.oldDirection),
                        bodyPart.setSnakeSpriteDirection(this.direction)
                    )
                    : (
                        bodyPart.update(
                            this.body[index - 1].oldX, 
                            this.body[index - 1].oldY, 
                            this.body[index - 1].oldDirection
                        ),
                        bodyPart.setSnakeSpriteDirection(this.body[index - 1].getDirection())   
                    )
```

Does this code not give you errors? it feels like you are using a different language here. you are putting commas in between lines of code. you are using a ternary operator as if it were just an if statement, or something like that. you're putting parenthesis around lines of code. i'm surprised its not giving errors in the console.

Edit 2:

Try replacing this strange ternary operator with this code instead:

```
   if( index == 0 ) {
                            bodyPart.update(this.x, this.y, this.oldDirection)
                            bodyPart.setSnakeSpriteDirection(this.direction)
    } else {
                            bodyPart.update(
                                this.body[index - 1].oldX, 
                                this.body[index - 1].oldY, 
                                this.body[index - 1].oldDirection
                            )
                            bodyPart.setSnakeSpriteDirection(this.body[index - 1].getDirection())   
    }
```

Comment: I have a setter that makes the same, but for me doesn't works, I don't  know why but returns undefined

Comment: @gfmois show us how you are using it on the actual object, so I can get a better idea.

Comment: I edited the question, I create the SnakeBody in Player class, this is the pastebin src: https://pastebin.com/YiuJxuPw

Comment: @gfmois I have added to my answer. check the edit.

Comment: I checked and tested, but the error is the same, this is a screenshot: https://ibb.co/dfk4zSt

Comment: @gfmois what are you trying to accomplish with that ternary operator in that code in my edit? do you understand how ternaries are supposed to work? why are you putting your code in parenthesis there, and separating the lines with commas? check my second edit, and try that code. it is what I guess you are trying to accomplish, but I'm not quite sure. this code is hard to parse.

Comment: Sorry for the difficult to analyze, I
change the ternary and same result, undefined in `this.oldDirection`, still don't know why it doesn't take the value of `this.direction`. (That ternary should have been changed before, sorry haha)

Comment: @gfmois show your new code. and show us where you set the player's direction. put it in the body of the question. you are going to want to start logging what values you are setting it to, to see if that code is running, and that you are setting it to the values you think you are setting it to.

Comment: The game code, where I initialize the Player class is this.